# Как определить площадь фигуры (в пикселях)?

Tags: c#, .net

Как определить площадь фигуры (в пикселях) из массива [Point(x1,y1), Point(x2,y2), .. Point(xN,yN)]?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Реализуйте [формулу площади Гаусса](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8_%D0%93%D0%B0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0) (она же shoelace)

```cs
private double getArea(Collection<Point> allPoint)
{
  double area = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < allPoint.Count; i++)
  {
      int j = (i + 1) % allPoint.Count;
      Point a = allPoint[i], b = allPoint[j];

      area += a.X * b.Y - a.Y * b.X;
  }
  return Math.Abs(area) / 2;
}
```